# Change hue of image from one color to another

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color

I have an image in blue and want to change it from blue to another color. An example shift is below:

[image]

The entire image I want to change the color hue. Instead of changing one contiguous area of colored pixels to another color, I just want to do the whole image. For example, changing it from blue to green/teal below, the light blue changed to light teal, the dark blue to dark teal, etc.

I'm not sure how to do this in either AI or PS. The artist I hired to make the above image said I could just change the spectrum of colors but what this means I'm not sure. He originally made the green and changed it to blue at my request and said it was straightforward how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing some methods I found this one a little more accurate.

A simple Photo filter made the job in a non destructive way.

See the settings below:[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's Photoshop, the select the layer and adjust hue based on the color wheel (https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-hue-saturation.html#apply_hue_saturation_adjustment).

If it's Illustrator, select the layer(s) and - typically - change the color with the standardcolor selector in the tool bar.

It's a bit difficult to pinpoint your needs exactly because you're asking for two completely different programs and your screenshots aren't including how the designer created it (i.e. the layers window).

Comment: I'm working with a flat image, ie one layer. Sorry for the ambiguity.